# There is a problem in paginate, the data disappears

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

There is a problem in numbering the interfaces, as when you press the next number, the data disappears vue js &laravel
I used laravel-vue-pagination*

```html
<pagination
  :data="userd.userdetails"
  @pagination-change-page="getResults()"
></pagination>
```

Methods

```js
getResults (page=1) {
  axios.get("/api/test?page=" + page).then(response => {
    this.userd.userdetails = response.data;
    this.userd.cards = response.data;
    console.log(this.userd.cards = response.data);
  }).catch(error=>console.log( error))
},
```

Comment: I think you want to use `@pagination-change-page="getResults"` (ie, remove `()`) as per the [example documentation](https://github.com/gilbitron/laravel-vue-pagination#usage)

Comment: Why are you assigning the same data to `this.userd.userdetails` and twice to `this.userd.cards`?

Comment: @phil because i get two array to the vue